# Form result queried with a PHP file and then returned into a seperate DIV with Jquery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, dynamic

I've been trying to get my form to submit its results to a PHP file, which are then queried and results outputted. My PHP file works with its query with variables passed with a standard PHP $_GET method but trying to work it with Jquery AJAX passing the values I'm struggling.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is what I'm currently at:

HTML File

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="options">
    <form id="form1">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Date:</td>
          <td><input name="date" type="text" id="datepicker" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Size:</td>
          <td><input name="size" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="result"> </div>
</div>
```

My current attempt at my script inserted at the top of the page with my PHP file named details.php.

```
<script>
$('#form1').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    type: $(this).attr('GET'), 
    url: $(this).attr('details.php'),
    success: function(response) {
      $('#result').html(response); 
    }
  });
  return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: $.attr is for getting attributes of an html element.  In this case its looking for <form id="form1" GET="something" details.php="something else"> neither of which exist. And aren't what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stops form from submitting naturally
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        //type: 'GET', //'GET' is default, set to 'POST' if you want.
        url: '/details.php',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#result').html(response); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Some additions. 1. details.php is a relative URL, it's better to use /details.php (or where it's placed on the server). 2. GET type is set by default (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), so there is no need to pass it.

Comment: Struggling to get this to work either.  Not creating any AJAX request says firebug.  Any possible solutions you may suggest?

Comment: Nothing on the Network XHR tab.  Its one of those situations where I'm pulling my hair out as I'm completely confused to why its not working.  Nature of the task in hand!

Comment: Looks correct. Try to check requests via network tab in Firebug. Of course, if there are no error(s) on console tab. If without result, try to pass error callback by adding to $.ajax({..,  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log(errorThrown);} }); to see what actually is wrong.